# How to find the generators of a deformed boost?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

I'm reading the paper [arXiv:gr-qc/0012051](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0012051) on doubly special relativity. In page 7, the author wants to find the generators of a deformed boost that preserves $$E^2 = p^2 + m^2 - l_p p^2 E$$ ($l_p$ is a constant) instead of the usual invariant $E^2 = p^2 + m^2$. He make the ansatz

$$B = i [p + l_p \Delta_1 (p^2, E)] \frac{\partial}{\partial E} + i [E + l_p \Delta_2 (p^2, E)] \frac{\partial}{\partial p}$$

for the boost generator $B$. Then, he says without explanation that $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are "easily determined" and he quickly concludes that $B$ must be

$$B = i p \frac{\partial}{\partial E} + i [E + l_p E^2 + l_p p^2/2] \frac{\partial}{\partial p}  .$$

How does he do that? And how can I check that this boost leaves $$E^2 = p^2 + m^2 - l_p p^2 E$$ invariant?

I'm familiar with group theory in quantum mechanics and have very weak knowledge on Lie groups.

Should I read a book on group theory to understand that properly? Any recommended book? (The shorter book in length, the better!)

Comment: I've not read the paper (nor am I familiar with doubly special relativity), but I wonder if the author is using the phrase "easily determined" in the (sadly) common way of "after several pages of algebraic manipulations."

Comment: Kyle, I have not problem with several pages of algebra. My problem is that I'm not comfortable enough with the concepts of generators and do not get what the author means. Maybe a general idea about what he says can help. I'm ready to do several pages algebra.